# Difference between Fixed Nuclei approximation, Born-Oppenheimer approximation, adiabatic nuclei approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, definition, approximations, born-oppenheimer-approximation

I was reading some papers and depending on the author some would use the terms Fixed Nuclei approximation, Born Oppenheimer approximation, adiabatic nuclei approximation almost interchangeably whilst others would use them in such a way as if they mean very different things.
Could anyone give me a brief and clear difference between all these approximations if such a thing exists.